# "too many memory references for mov" error when embedding assembly in C++

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc, vmware, inline-assembly

I wrote a program to check if I am working with virtual machine or not using assembly for linux. When I compile it, it shows the error "too many memory references for mov". How can I fix this? Can you guys help me check if my program is correct or not?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool IsInsideVMWare() {
    bool rc = true;
    try { 
        asm (
                "push   edx;"
                "push   ecx;"
                "push   ebx;"
    
                "mov    eax, 'VMXh';"
                "mov    ebx, 0;" // any value but not the MAGIC VALUE
                "mov    ecx, 10;" // get VMWare version
                "mov    edx, 'VX';" // port number
    
                "in     eax, dx;" // read port on return EAX returns the VERSION
                "cmp    ebx, 'VMXh';" // is it a reply from VMWare?
                "setz   [rc];" // set return value
    
                "pop    ebx;"
                "pop    ecx;"
                "pop    edx;"
        );
    }
    catch(const bool a) {
        rc = false;
    }
    return rc;
}

int main() {
    if (IsInsideVMWare()) {
        cout << "VM Ware";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: How do you expect that inline asm statement to `throw` a C++ exception?  Is this compiled for Windows with SEH?  I don't know if MSVC magically does anything for you with try/catch around an `_asm{}` block, or whether GCC or clang for Windows would once you rewrite it as Jester shows with an asm statement.

Comment: Yeah the try-catch may be totally useless on linux. In fact I get a segfault when not running under vmware.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have copied code intended for MSVC. I have converted to gcc inline assembly for you:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool IsInsideVMWare() {
    bool rc = true;
    try { 
        const uint32_t magic = 0x564D5868; // VMXh
        const uint16_t port = 0x5658; // VX
        uint32_t result, flag;
        asm ("in %[port], %[result]"
           : [result] "=a" (result), "=b" (flag)
           : "0" (magic), "c" (10), [port] "d" (port));
        rc = (flag == magic);
    }
    catch(const bool a) {
        rc = false;
    }
    return rc;
}

int main() {
    if (IsInsideVMWare()) {
        cout << "VM Ware";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Note that when not running under VMWare the `in` instruction requires privileges otherwise you get a segfault that the `try`/`catch` will not handle. As a workaround you can run as root and enable the privileges while hoping that accessing the vmware port will be harmless on your system:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool IsInsideVMWare() {
    const uint32_t magic = 0x564D5868; // VMXh
    const uint16_t port = 0x5658; // VX
    uint32_t result, flag;
    iopl(3);
    asm ("in %[port], %[result]"
           : [result] "=a" (result), "=b" (flag)
           : "0" (magic), "c" (10), [port] "d" (port));
    return (flag == magic);
}

int main() {
    if (IsInsideVMWare()) {
        cout << "VM Ware";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Depending on your requirements, it may be better to check the DMI product or vendor name, both of which contain "VMWare" on my system.

Comment: *intended for MSVC* - and written by someone who didn't understand MSVC inline asm.  The push/pop inside the `asm{}` block is useless; MSVC is also going to save/restore those regs.  Unless it was written for ancient Borland Turbo C++ or something, which doesn't.